# Can you run two different Stripe accounts as two different gateways in Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Does anyone know if there are any drawbacks/gotchas to having multiple Stripe gateways setup in commerce for Craft Subs?

If I wanted to have two sites on my craft install and for them to both use Commerce Subs, but for each site to have it's own Stripe account (i.e 2 stripe gateways with different API details in both)

Would that work ok with stripe callbacks etc etc etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, and yes it will work.

This text here is to meet the minimum answer length.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks Luke! I thought it would be ok as I couldn't see any obvious reason why not, but had to check!!